# Stackhero occasionally throws 500 errors

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, amazon-s3, heroku

I have a Laravel/Vue mix web application hosted on Heroku with a Stackhero Object Storage bucket. When I refresh the main page, it requests about a dozen images from the bucket, but some of the requests return the 500 error and they may vary every now and then. I have no problem opening those images in my browser on a new tab. The bucket's CORS is properly configured. I raised the maximum number of concurrent requests up to 200, no change:
[image]

I wonder what might be the issue.

Comment: did you check `/storage/laravel.log`?

Comment: @sta yep, nothing

Comment: In the network tab in the browser to see if the error is specified? Without any specification, we are playing a guessing game.

Comment: @mrhn no, the response body is empty

Answer (score 0):

Adrien from Stackhero here :)

Are 500 errors generated by MinIO? If so, please login to your Stackhero dashboard (via the Heroku dashboard) and contact the support to see what is happening exactly.

Best,
Adrien

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).